# Postgres - Only sometimes want to display a digit to the left of decimal separator

Tags: sql, postgresql

Right now I am using numeric(4,3) data type to represent a percentage in decimal form (ex. 57.2% = .572). The problem is, when I save it's ALWAYS displaying these decimals with a digit to the left of the decimal separator. So in other words it is displaying as 0.572 when I want it to display as .572  .However, there are occasions when I want a digit to the left of the separator(like when displaying the 1.000 ,meaning 100%).

What is the data type that I should use to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't store it at all because it breaks normalization (don't store calculated values).  Instead, I would do the math and format the result using either sql or application code, depending on how you plan to display this.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> SELECT to_char(0.157, '0.99%');
> ```
>
> ```
> | to_char |
> | :------ |
> |  0.16%  |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT to_char(0.157, '9.99%');
> ```
>
> ```
> | to_char |
> | :------ |
> |   .16%  |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=86fe6edba51fd97f0a7a2578c4681123)*

Comment: Wouldn't that essentially display it in character/text form? I wanted to leave it a number (if possible).

Comment: No, data type is `numeric(4,3)`

Comment: That wouldn't modify the data type?

Comment: You cannot modify how postgres store data types.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are numbers.  If you want to format them in a particular way, you can use `to_char()`.  This is particularly true if you want to format them in different ways under different circumstances.

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html) covers the situations you describe.

Comment: Darn, I was afraid the answer was going to be to display it in character form

Comment: If you include the percentage sign, it has to be character form.

Comment: @NickT You can only display numbers in character form, right?

Comment: Yes, but I want a number data type. Not one where you can also enter in alphabet characters